# Flair doesn't display properly. Flair 500 Error

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

My MSE flair stopped displaying as can be see in the [flair page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/752/americo-tavares/flair), contrary to my [TEX.SE flair](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1862/americo-tavares/flair).

[image]

I have no idea what's the reason for this behavior.

ADDED. [This flair page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/38053/julien/flair) shows the default math.SE and the combined SE flairs, but not the clean, dark and hot dog stand math.SE flairs.

ADDED 2. I've just seen that all my MSE flairs now show properly, but the flair page mentioned in my last edit remains unchanged.

[image]

ADDED 3. This bug is [MSO Flair 500 Error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170997/flair-500-error), as pointed out by  Martin Sleziak, and has already been fixed and tagged (status-completed) there. Apparently, now it is fixed here too.

Comment: Some flairs seem to work, so it is not a system-wide problem. [This flair page](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/6792/awllower/flair) shows the math.SE flair, but not the stackexchange flair.

Comment: @robjohn: the page you linked to works for me (as in both the site-wide and maths ones work).

Comment: @robjohn: the page you linked to works for me too.

Comment: @WillieWong: interesting. All I see is [a text link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u1O6I.png). It doesn't show the flair.

Comment: MSO: [Flair 500 Error](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170997/flair-500-error). It is tagged (status-completed) now.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks! Apparently it is now fixed here too. Do you how and who decides the (status-completed) tag in this meta site?

Comment: It seems that this kind of tags can be added only by mods, see the tag-excerpt from [meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/moderator-tags/info).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks!

Comment: tagged status completed due to the link Martin pointed out.

Comment: I still didnt get where to paste that snippet of code !! Can anyone give me little details ?

Comment: @Loophole To show the flair I pasted the HTML code it on my blog.

Comment: blogs are blocked for me to use. I saw that code [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/4492881/loophole?tab=flair). I want to know where exactly should I paste it ?

Comment: @Loophole You may post it e.g. in your profile page (Edit Profile & Settings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hum, interestingly, when I go to the link `http://math.stackexchange.com/users/flair/752.png` which should point to your flair icon, something tells me

> The image .... cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

While `wget` says

```
~ $ wget http://math.stackexchange.com/users/flair/752.png
--2013-03-08 17:01:55--  http://math.stackexchange.com/users/flair/752.png
Resolving math.stackexchange.com (math.stackexchange.com)... 198.252.206.16
Connecting to math.stackexchange.com (math.stackexchange.com)|198.252.206.16|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2013-03-08 17:01:55 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

which strongly suggests that it is *them*, and not you.

Comment: I had seen that message in the link `http://math.stackexchange.com/users/flair/752.png`. What's `wget`?

Comment: `wget` is a utility for noninteractive downloads of stuff from the internet. Mainly I was wondering whether the message is a Firefox message (that the flair was somehow generated but broken, in which case the download would've succeeded and I can check out what's wrong with the `png` file) or due to something being borked on the server (which turns out to be the case).

Comment: Thanks! And the server mentioned in your message is the  math.stackexchange.com server, if I understand it right.

Comment: As discovered by Martin Sleziak this is MSO [Flair 500 Error](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170997/flair-500-error), which is tagged (status-completed). Apparently it is now fixed here too. Do you how and who decides the (status-completed) tag in this meta site?

Comment: ... According to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/moderator-tags/info) it seems to be the mods.